Why Blazor bUnit test is asking for services registration
I have a Blazor project that uses several services registered in program.cs.
If I add any component to the project and then prepare tests for it in the Test project, it still requires that I register the services in the main project. For example, here is my program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService2>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITenantProvider, TenantProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AppState>();
builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ErrorLoggingService , ErrorLoggingService>();

Now I add a simple component Test2.razor to the Pages folder:
<h3>Test2</h3>

@code {

}


Now I setup a test in the Test project:
using Clinic.Pages;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tests
{
    public class TestTests : TestContext
    {

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // Arrange
            var cut = RenderComponent<Test2>();

            // Assert that content of the h3 match
            cut.Find("p").MarkupMatches("<h3>Test2</h3>");
        }

        
    }
}

When I run the test, I get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot provide a value for property 'DataService' on type 'Clinic.Pages.Test2'. There is no registered service of type 'Clinic.Models.DataService'.

Even though component Test2 does not use DataService or any other service. Why is that?
